# How to show actionbar after hiding it in android?

Tags: android

I tried to show my action bar with following line :-

**getActionBar().show();**

After hided it with the following line :-

**getActionBar().hide();**

but no action is done , the action bar didn't appear again.

Any suggest ?

**Note :** 
 My class extends FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that instead of using the default ActionBar, you should be using a Toolbar, which will be better supported across most of the devices and will allow all kind of customizations. 
Follow this helpful [Android Developer - Toolbar tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).